# how to load second url after the first finishing

Tags: android, webview

i wanna load a second url after the first url finish loading but it's not working  ,
 why he stay only on first url ?
 here is my code :

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvDisplay);
    // Enable Javascript
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    String url ="http://www.google.com";


    if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
        url = "http://" + url;



            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
     webView.loadUrl(url);

}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String url2="http://www.facebook.com";
            webView.loadUrl(url2);

    }

}
```

it's not working, if any have idea please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason it's not working is because it loads url then url2 then url2 then url2 and it's a loop so when url2 finishes loading first time it starts to load it again and again so in the end you don't see anything because it's too fast... what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: yes exactly like you seed , i want to load the first url and when i's loaded url2 load

Comment: then how about deleting onPageFinished(...){...} and call like this: webView.loadUrl(url);  webView.loadUrl(url2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes what you need & fixes your activity memory leak (inner classes should be static in activities or else is a memory leak)

```
private static class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    private String[] mStrings = {"http://www.facebook.com"};
    private int index = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (index < mStrings.length)
            view.loadUrl(mStrings[index++]);
    }

}
```

Comment: tanks a lot now the problem is fixed